# How to Add Resize Handle in C# or VB.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How can I have the resize handles (the little squares or circles on the corners) during run time in my controls? Is there a component that allow me to have it? Or someone has a piece of code to do it?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What framework? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean windows form applications, Try these links:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17245/Runtime-Control-Resizer
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24096/Drawing-Resizable-Controls-at-Runtime
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13184/Runtime-resizable-controls

You mean something else, Comment this answer to talk about.

Hope to be helpful

Comment: @Jose Roberto Barros, Check answer mark will be appreciated if you got to your answer.

Comment: Your welcome my friend